# Conditional promise chain

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm looking to write some code that chains together some promises. I have a condition that based on the result of one promise I either call the next function that returns a promise and continue chaining another few functions, or I do nothing (effectively end the promise chain).

I have the following three possible solutions, I kinda think they all are a bit messy though.

Here is my first approach, what I dislike here is the nested promises.

```
initalAsyncCall()
  .then((shouldContinue) => {
    if (shouldContinue) {
      return nextStep()
        .then(() => anotherStep())
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    handleError(error);
  })
```

Here is my second. This one seems a bit longer and possibly harder to read

```
const shouldContinuePromise = initialAsyncCall();
const nextStepPromise = shouldContinuePromise.then((shouldContinue) => {
  if (shouldContinue) return nextStep();
});
Promise.all([shouldContinuePromise, nextStepPromise])
  .spread((shouldContinue) => {
    if (shouldContinue) return anotherStep();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    handleError(error);
  });
```

And finally here is my last approach. What I don't like here is I am throwing an error when it's not really an error.

```
initalAsyncCall()
  .then((shouldContinue) => {
    if (!shouldContinue) throw new HaltException()
    return nextStep();
  })
  .then(() => anotherStep())
  .catch(HaltException, (ex) => {
    // do nothing... maybe some logging
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    handleError(error);
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first approach seems fine, to avoid the nesting you can return the promise and add an extra then block for the nested part like this

```js
initalAsyncCall()
  .then((shouldContinue) => {
    if (shouldContinue) {
      return nextStep()
    } else {
      throw Error('skip next step')
    }
  })
  .then(() => anotherStep())
  .catch((error) => {
    handleError(error);
  })
```

If you don't like throwing an unnecessary error in the third approach, You could use async/await to have more control and get rid of the function scope/nesting problem, which is also recommended for the new nodejs versions due to better error stack traces.

```js
try {
    const shouldContinue = await initalAsyncCall()
    if (shouldContinue) {
      await nextStep()
      await anotherStep()
// or await Promise.all([nextStep(), anotherStep()]) if they're not dependent
    }
}
catch (error) {
  handleError(error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with my first approach. I was refactoring some old code and came across this. I was happy to leave as is but was curious to see what the rest of the community thought about it. Async await probably the way to go for any future code anyway